# How do I talk to a WCF service from a Firefox extension?

Tags: wcf, firefox-addon

I wrote a simple WCF service and verified I could call it from an asp.net web application. Now i want to call the same service from a firefox extension.

Looking at the example here, http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.com/2008/02/calling-wcf-service-from-javascript.html I figured if i get the javascript proxy in step 7, I will be able to call it from the javascript in my firefox extension.

But when i load firefox with the extension, it says "Type undefined" in the error console and points to the Type.registerNamespace line at the start of the javascript proxy.

Does the generated proxy only work from another .net application? How should I be going about this?

Update: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/SOAP_in_Gecko-based_Browsers talks about how to deal with calling a web service from Firefox. So if we have the wsdl for the wcf service we should be able to do this from the extension.

Comment: If your update answers  your question, then please add an answer with that information, then accept that answer.

Comment: yeah working on it, once i find a solution I'll update.

Comment: Native WSDL and SOAP support was removed from Mozilla 1.9/Firefox 3. This article https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_SOAP_in_XULRunner_1.9 seems to give an alternative way for it to work, but I haven't got it successfully talking to the web service yet. I'm new to web programming in general so it'll take me some time to figure out if I'm doing this right. If someone else knows of a working example using this approach with a SOAP 1.2 based WSDL let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Use WCF to return plain xml (not SOAP) or JSON.  JSON may be an excellent choice for sure, because you will be consuming from xul/JS..